# Multiple string inputs with exit from loop....without array

Tags: java, string

So i have updated my code but it does a very strange thing.  When two inputs are entered it returns the longest and shortest and the rest of the variables. However, when more than two are input it returns the longest...great...but for shortest it just returns the word that is shorter than longest as opposed to the shortest string inputted.....what is going on :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringReporting
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String word ="";
        String words = "";
        String result ="";
        int count = 0;
        int shortest = 1;
        int longest = 1;
        int sumOfLengths = 0;
        double averageLength = 0;
        String shortestWord = "";
        String longestWord = "";
        while (!word.equals("x"))
        {
            count ++;
            System.out.println ("Please enter String " + count + ", enter x 
            to exit: ");
            word = in.nextLine();
            words  += "String " + count + ": " + word + "\n";
            sumOfLengths += word.length();
            if (word.length()>longest)
            {
                longest= word.length();
                longestWord = word;
            }   
            else if(word.length()> shortest && word.length() < longest)
            {
                shortest = word.length();
                shortestWord = word;
            }   


        }


        averageLength = (sumOfLengths-1) / (count-1);
        System.out.println ("shortest string entered: 
        " + shortestWord + ", with a length of: " + shortest);
        System.out.println ("longest string entered: " 
        + longestWord + ", with a length of: " + longest);
        System.out.println (" sum of all lengths: " + 
        (sumOfLengths-1));
        System.out.println ("number of strings: " + count);
        System.out.println ("average string length : " + averageLength);
```

Comment: Hint: you don't need to store the words at all. Do the processing as you read the words one by one.

Comment: Create some vars before the loop and update them as you read the words.Ex: `String longestWord, shortestWord; int totalLength, wordCount;`

Comment: But you're not even trying to do something with the given input, looks to me like you gave up quite easily and now expects us to do the homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a school exercise, so I'm going to try to help you without plainly giving the answer.

You only need one loop, and should not loop over all the words again after they've all been entered. Once "x" is entered, the results to be printed should already have been calculated (or need minimal finishing, like calculating the average). You can print several values at the end, there's no need to put it all into 1 String.

If you need more help, feel free to ask!

Comment: Awesome thank you for all your advice.  Will work on it tonight :)

Comment: Hiya, i have updated my question with a nearly conplete code but for some reason, with more than 2 inputs the shortest string is returned as 1 less than the longest even if it isnt the shortra6t string! What have i done wrong?

Comment: Your second `if` checks if the new word's length is between the shortest and the longest, and if it is, saves it as the new shortest. This does not find the shortest word, since you're always saving a word that is *longer* than the shortest word. You need to check if the new word is *shorter* than the shortest word so far. Other than that, looks great! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a variable max and for every word inputted check if it's greater than the max then change the max to the new word
and same for the min ( don't forget to check if min is still "" then change it to first word ) also you need a counter to count the length of all words inputted, and a counter for the number of words that has been inputted to calculate average word length in the end
And to output them as string 1: hey string 2: hello world etc..
You need to do like this

```
Words  += "String " + counter + ": " + word + "\n";
```

Comment: Hiya, i have updated my question with a nearly conplete code but for some reason, with more than 2 inputs the shortest string is returned as 1 less than the longest even if it isnt the shortra6t string!  What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(word.length()> shortest && word.length() < longest)
            {
                shortest = word.length();
                shortestWord = word;
            }
```

it should be word.length() < shortest, but shortest is initially 1 so it might not pass it, that's why you should set shortest initially to Integer.MAX_VALUE, and longest to 0 (cause if the longest word is one character it won't detect it)
Also this word.length() < longest is not necessary
Also this should't be in the else since the user might input one word only and this one word is the shortest and the longest at the same time